# Fullcalendar group events in week daygrid

Tags: vue.js, events, fullcalendar, group

How can I customize the week view to group events in my calendar, where each group gets its own row, similar to the following image?

It should look like this:

[image]

Is there a simple solution to achieve something like this? I don't want times of day, I just want the days from Monday to Sunday and then the events for those days, but a separate row for each event group.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view-demo <-- this but with grouped rows

I am using vue 3 and fullcalendar

I tried the resource timeline and I tried to create a custom view. But there should be an easier solution to achive something like this?

Edit:

I have now attempted to achieve what I have in mind using the resource timeline. For this purpose, I have hidden the resource area, and so far, it already looks almost like what I would like to have.

However, problems arise with the 'dateclick' function. I would like to have this function triggered whenever I click on the column for the day. However, currently, it only works on the resource row.

current:
[image]

target:
[image]

I just had the hope that achieving something like this would be easier. Such as with an option for grouping, for example

Comment: This looks like exactly the use case for the resource timeline view. You mention wanting an "easier" solution...but what exactly was difficult about using the resource timeline view? Did you encounter a specific problem that we can help with?

Comment: Why do you need that bottom area to be clickable? What is the purpose you want to achieve with that? In a resource-aware view you can't select anything which isn't associated with a specific resource. Also why did you hide the resource names? That will just confuse users I think - they will wonder why the two 8am events are not next to each other horizontally, because it isn't obvious, and it's very counterintuitive, without the resource names to show that they belong to different categories. You seem to be aiming to create a very strange layout which won't be user-friendly.

Comment: it is a request from a customer. The times are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Customers don't always ask for sensible things. Part of our job as developers is to point out occasions when the request is illogical, and/or - as in this case - impossible or at least very expensive/complicated to achieve, and then to explain the difficulties to the customer, and propose a more sensible and/or simpler alternative which still meets the overall basic goal of the feature.